# How to update document object value in loop (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

Hi folks i am a beginer to Java script so appologies if this is a dumb question.
I am trying to put the following in a for loop but I can't seem to get it to work.

if (rowID==1) 
    {
        document.form1.class_titleDis_1.value=class_title;
    }
if (rowID==2) 
    {
        document.form1.class_titleDis_2.value=class_title;

```
}
```

This is what I tried

```
var i=1;
for (i=1;i<=2;i++)
{
  document.form1.(class_titleDis_)+i.value=class_title;
}
```

I would be really grateful for any suggestions. 
Graham

Answer (score 0):

```
document.form1.(class_titleDis_)+i.value=class_title;
```

Should likely be:

```
document.form1['class_titleDis_'+i].value=class_title;
```

Comment: You are an absoulte star, worked perfectly! You would not believe how many permutations of this I had tried. So many many thanks. Graham